# Swapping two elements in a template type list. Seeking most efficient algorithm

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

`Swap<T, Position1, Position2, Pack>::type`, where `Pack` consists of elements of type T, is to return the pack with the elements in Position1 and Position2 swapped. My solution below is NOT the most efficient.  There should be a way to accomplish this very cleanly, **without visiting any element twice**.  Can someone think of it?

```
// ReplaceElement replaces the element of a pack with a specified position (0 being the first position) with a specified value.
template <typename T, std::size_t, std::size_t, T, typename, typename> struct ReplaceElementHelper;

template <typename T, std::size_t Position, std::size_t CurrentPosition, T NewValue, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, T... Accumulated>
struct ReplaceElementHelper<T, Position, CurrentPosition, NewValue, Z<First, Rest...>, Z<Accumulated...>>
    : ReplaceElementHelper<T, Position, CurrentPosition + 1, NewValue, Z<Rest...>, Z<Accumulated..., First>> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t Position, T NewValue, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, T... Accumulated>
struct ReplaceElementHelper<T, Position, Position, NewValue, Z<First, Rest...>, Z<Accumulated...>> {
    using type = Z<Accumulated..., NewValue, Rest...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t, T, typename> struct ReplaceElement;

template <typename T, std::size_t Position, T NewValue, template <T...> class Z, T... Ts>
struct ReplaceElement<T, Position, NewValue, Z<Ts...>> : ReplaceElementHelper<T, Position, 0, NewValue, Z<Ts...>, Z<>> {
    static_assert (Position < sizeof...(Ts), "Error!  Invalid position for ReplaceElement.");
};

// Swapping two elements of specified positions in a pack.
template <typename, std::size_t, std::size_t, typename> struct Swap;

template <typename T, std::size_t Position1, std::size_t Position2, template <T...> class Z, T... Ts>
struct Swap<T, Position1, Position2, Z<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr T a[sizeof...(Ts)] = {Ts...};
    using type = typename ReplaceElement<T, Position2, a[Position1], typename ReplaceElement<T, Position1, a[Position2], Z<Ts...>>::type>::type;
};
```

You can tell that my solution visits `all` the elements before Position1 (or Position2) twice.  There should be no need for that.  I know there must a solution that avoids this, but I can't think of it.

Comment: Why does visiting an element matter at all?  This is compile time stuff...

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter from a practical point of view (unless the list is very long and a lot of swaps are made).  But if there is a cleaner solution, I want to learn what it is.  It's like solving a math problem but seeking a more elegant proof.  That's the best way to get better I think, because I'm still learning.

Comment: The problem is a lot of template expansion depends on recursive types, at which point it becomes completely ambiguous what "visiting an element" even _means_.  I have an idea, but one could say it "visits each element" zero times, N times, or N^2 times, and all are right.

Comment: Minimizing the number of inheritance steps?  Is that more objective to measure?  Above, when `CurrentPosition` switches to `CurrentPosition + 1`, then that is one step that I'm referring to.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to minimize the number of _template instantiations_?  There is no inheritance here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided that `value_pack` is defined somewhat like

```
template <typename T, T... v>
struct value_pack {
    static constexpr T array[] {v...};
    static constexpr std::size_t len = sizeof...(v);
    using type = value_pack;
};
template <typename T, T... v>
constexpr T value_pack<T, v...>::array[];
```

Then a solution in C++14 looks like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t p1, std::size_t p2,
          typename pack,
          typename=std::make_index_sequence<pack::len>>
struct Swap;
template <typename T, std::size_t p1, std::size_t p2,
          typename pack, std::size_t...indices>
struct Swap<T, p1, p2, pack, std::index_sequence<indices...>> :
    value_pack<T,  pack::array[indices==p1? p2 : indices==p2? p1 : indices]...> {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3517764cf567d18a). If a C++14 standard library is not available, you can implement `make_index_sequence` yourself - numerous examples are scattered across SO.

Comment: Heh, I thought of the indices trick, but `indices==p1? p2 : indices==p2? p1 : indices` never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this solution might be faster than Columbo's solution because it starts at the front of the pack and moves to the right and stops at Position2 without visiting any element after Position2 (which I think is the shortest route it can take):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, std::size_t, std::size_t, typename> struct Swap;
template <typename, std::size_t, std::size_t, typename, typename, typename> struct SwapHelper;

template <typename T, std::size_t Position1, std::size_t Position2, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, T... Head, T... Middle>
struct SwapHelper<T, Position1, Position2, Z<First, Rest...>, Z<Head...>, Z<Middle...>> :
    SwapHelper<T, Position1 - 1, Position2 - 1, Z<Rest...>, Z<Head..., First>, Z<Middle...>> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t Position2, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, T... Head, T... Middle>
struct SwapHelper<T, 0, Position2, Z<First, Rest...>, Z<Head...>, Z<Middle...>> :
    SwapHelper<T, 0, Position2 - 1, Z<Rest...>, Z<Head...>, Z<Middle..., First>> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest, T... Head, T FirstOfMiddle, T... Middle>
struct SwapHelper<T, 0, 0, Z<First, Rest...>, Z<Head...>, Z<FirstOfMiddle, Middle...>> {
    using type = Z<Head..., First, Middle..., FirstOfMiddle, Rest...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Position1, std::size_t Position2, template <T...> class Z, T... Ts>
struct Swap<T, Position1, Position2, Z<Ts...>> : std::conditional<(Position1 < Position2),
        SwapHelper<T, Position1, Position2, Z<Ts...>, Z<>, Z<>>,
        SwapHelper<T, Position2, Position1, Z<Ts...>, Z<>, Z<>>
    >::type {};

// Testing
template <int...> struct Sequence;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        typename Swap<int, 2, 5, Sequence<0,2,4,6,8,10,12>>::type,
        Sequence<0,2,10,6,8,4,12>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        typename Swap<int, 5, 2, Sequence<0,2,4,6,8,10,12>>::type,
        Sequence<0,2,10,6,8,4,12>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true
}
```

How to benchmark two compile-time processes?